# Custom filter in excel across columns

Tags: excel

I have to filter data from an excel sheet.I have data separated line by line across 10 columns and I have to filter data present only in column A2 and A8.Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Mohit, welcome to SO, do read our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and our [on-topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it is currently written, it doesn't seem to belong on SO

Comment: Can you share some code/UI?

Comment: I haven't wrote any code as of now. Below is the sample data file

Comment: I haven't wrote any code as of now. Below is the sample data file"ID":             "i-3861f5b4",
                "PublicIp": "176.34.65.244",
         "PublicDns":"ec2-176-34-65-244.euwest1.compute.amazonaws.com",
                "PrivateDns": "ip-10-123-157-222.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
                "State": "0",
                "StateName": "pending",
                "IsActive": false,
                "Type": "engine",
                "Time": "2016-05-24T05:49:39.000Z",
                "Size": "m3.large",
                "Port": 1097
Need to filter datawith PublicIp and Type

Comment: @MohitSharma - Share your file online so that some one can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the same using Notepad++. 
First, Find and search all the data which needs to be filtered.
Click on Mark tab, select Bookmark line and click on Mark All.This will mark your search field and bookmark everything
Next, go to search->Bookmark->Remove Unmarked lines.

Now,only the required data will be available!